# How to keep radio button and label in the same line with long label content in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I have an issue with an HTML radio button and its label. I want to keep the radio button and label in the same line. But if the label text is very long, the label will sit below the radio button.
html:

```
<div class="form-check fs-3 mb-3">
  <input id="low-3" name="low-3" type="radio" value="light">
  <label for="low-3">very long very long very long very long context</label>
</div>
```

How can I keep the label on the same line as the radio button?

Comment: Why did you remove the image? It gives a clear, simple display of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Bootstrap's `_reboot.scss` file sets `label { display: inline-block; }` by default, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Solution

Simply set the Bootstrap `d-inline` class on the `<label>`, which is equivalent to `label { display: inline; }`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-check fs-3 mb-3">
    <input id="low-3" name="low-3" type="radio" value="light">
    <label class="d-inline" for="low-3">very long very long very long very long very long very long very long context</label>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now your label has inline-block display property so your elements on different lines. Wrap the input and the label and set "d-inline" class for the label and your elements will be on the same line.

Like this:

```
   <div>
    <input id="low-3" name="low-3" type="radio" value="light" />
    <label for="low-3" class="d-inline">very long very long very long very long context</label>
  </div>
```